# Unnest a map of array of type date to rows Presto

Tags: presto, unnest

I have a table of the following:

```
---
id | map
---
1 | {"LEGAL_HOLD": ["2021-06-10"], "RETURNED": ["2021-06-10", "2022-07-01"]}
2 | {"RETURNED": ["2021-06-10", "2022-07-10"]}
```

Want (only the key "RETURNED" values):

```
---
id | dates
---
1  | 2021-06-10 
1  | 2022-07-01
2  | 2021-06-10
2  | 2022-07-10
```

Attempt:

```
with table as (
SELECT 1 as id, MAP(ARRAY['LEGAL_HOLD','RETURNED'], ARRAY[date('2021-06-10'),date('2022-07-01')]) as maps
union all  
SELECT 2 as id, MAP(ARRAY['LEGAL_HOLD','RETURNED'], ARRAY[date('2021-06-10'),date('2022-07-10')]) as maps)

select id, date
from table
cross join unnest (table) as t(type, date)
where type = 'RETURNED'
```

This attempt only returns

```
---
id | dates
---
1  | [2021-06-10, 2022-07-01]
2  | [2021-06-10, 2022-07-10]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

```
with table as (
SELECT 1 as id, MAP(ARRAY['LEGAL_HOLD','RETURNED'], ARRAY[date('2021-06-10'),date('2022-07-01')]) as maps
union all  
SELECT 2 as id, MAP(ARRAY['LEGAL_HOLD','RETURNED'], ARRAY[date('2021-06-10'),date('2022-07-10')]) as maps)

select id, date
from table
cross join unnest (table['RETURNED']) as t(date)
```